# Manage global lists of Azure DevOps (TFS) by code

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops, tfs

I can export and import `global list` with [witadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/manage-global-lists-for-work-item-types?view=azure-devops-2022).

```
witadmin exportgloballist /collection:http://imtfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:c:\temp\globallist.xml
witadmin importgloballist /collection:http://imtfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:c:\temp\globallist.xml
```

Can I do the same by code? Can I do it by C# with `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`? Can I do it with REST?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/lists?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Or Team foundation Client:

```
WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient ProcessHttpClient = Connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingProcessHttpClient>();

var lists = ProcessHttpClient.GetListsMetadataAsync().Result;
var list = ProcessHttpClient.GetListAsync(lists[1].Id).Result;
list.Items.Add("PREPROD");
var updatedList = ProcessHttpClient.UpdateListAsync(list, list.Id).Result;
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I can build and run the code. But when I call 'GetListsMetadataAsync()' the TFS returns "400/Bad Request". In fiddler I see that it tries to use api-version=6.0-preview.1. Do you have any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @koalabruder I use this client: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/16.170.0?_src=template

Comment: I use the same client with the latest version 16.170.0. I am able to handle workitems like Bugs and User Stories. But I am not able to use GetListsMetadataAsync().

Comment: @koalabruder I`ve tested on Azure DevOps services..... Which TFS version do you use? Do you use PAT with all permissions?

Comment: I am using "Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1" with an PAT with all Permissions